# ASP.net C# page, 2 DropDownList on page with 2 onSelectedIndexChange only the first one fires

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<tr>
    <td>
        State:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="stateListBox" CssClass="ListBox" SelectionMode="Single"
            DataTextField="stateorregion" DataValueField="stateorregion" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="populateCourseListBox" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Course:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="courseListBox" CssClass="ListBox" SelectionMode="Single"
            DataTextField="courseName" DataValueField="course_id" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            OnSelectedIndexChange="onCourseSelectedIndexChange" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
</tr>
```

These 2 DropDownList should perform the same way, populateCourseListBox gets called and onCourseSelectedIndexChange is not getting called, no compiler errors, no runtime errors. I am missing something obvious here?

The idea is that when I select a state, I want to populate the golf courses for the state, then once I have selected a golf course, I want to be able to select a tee box.  When I change the state courselistbox gets populated, however when I select a course, page_load is called but that's it.

Comment: Not a direct fix for your problem but perhaps investigate the ASP.net ajax tool kit and it's casading dropdowns: http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx and http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/cascadingdropdown/using-cascadingdropdown-with-a-database-cs

Comment: I take it you've added a break point on `onCourseSelectedIndexChange` to step through the code in it and that break point is not being hit?

Comment: Replace "OnSelectedIndexChange" to "OnSelectedIndexChanged" in your course DDL. there's a spelling mistake

Comment: Ok, will add this as the answer and you accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `OnSelectedIndexChange` to `OnSelectedIndexChanged` in your course DDL. There's a spelling mistake.

If a control property is not an event identifier it'll be considered as a custom property. that's why you didn't get any errors. :)

[And, you'll be better off if you could make use of the `CascadingDropDown` control from Ajax Control Tool kit. This helps you to cascade select multiple drop downs. Have a look at this example](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx).